# Creating a large array of base 6 in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an assignment in C++ where the computer has to guess a sequence of numbers between a large range. However, the range is in base 6. I'm trying to create a large array (around 1300 elements) that can be incremented and manipulated (certain elements that contain numbers in a specific place can be removed/not incremented), but I don't even know how to create an array (or vector) in something other than base 10. Every time I look for help online I can only find stuff about base classes and pointers, which doesn't help me.

To summarize: I need to create a large array/vector that contains all the numbers from 0000 to 5555 (base 6) that can be incremented one element at a time and can have multiple elements removed at once. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't use `vector<int>`  and append all the numbers from 0000 to 5555(base 6) to the vector?

Comment: There are only integer values in the array. The base is a construct for display of numeric values as text.

Comment: `However, the range is in base 6` What does this mean? The base only matters when you need to write a number out as a sequence of digits - not when you perform arithmetic on that number. In particular, 5555 (base 6) == 1295 (base 10) == 6^4-1

Comment: I've tried the setbase function but that only seems to utilize base 8, 10, and 16. How can I convert each number to base 6? Also I can't have 3, 2, or 1 digit numbers like 135 or 12, all the leading zeroes have to be included as well. If I just append all the numbers, won't the result be truncated and remove the leading zeroes?

Comment: Numbers do not have leading zeros either. Padded text might. Is this will question about how to *display* in base 6 with a padding? The text representation is separate from the integer value itself.

Comment: A little added context may be useful here. I'm making a game where the computer has to guess a 4 digit code between 0 and 5. If the guess is wrong, it outputs a 2 digit response. The first digit tells you how many numbers in the guess are in the right place in the secret code, the second tells you how many numbers are in the secret code but in the wrong place.

The reason I'm creating the set is to list the possible guesses the computer can make. It starts with 0000, then makes the next guess based on the response.

Comment: In other words, the parlour game of "Mastermind".

Comment: Yep, although I think it traditionally uses colors. Also in this case, the computer is making the guesses.

Comment: It's not a number in base 6. Numbers in base N have the property that on addition, digits overflow to the next higher digit if they reach N. You do not have addition nor overflow into the next digit here. Instead, you have an array of 4 values, each of which fits in 3 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Computers don't normally store numbers in base 10; they use base 2. What the issue is here is really the external representation of the numbers; i.e., what you see.

The API std::strtoi allows you to specify what base the number being converted is in. Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) link.

On the output side, you will need to convert your number from the normal base 2 into base 6. I'm not going to write that code here. Look up an existing API or write your own. But the gist of the answer is: store in base 2, read in and write out strings in base 6.

Comment: There is no need to convert *from* base 2. There are only integer values. For this task, how the integers  are stored by the computer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to make a game like that, I'd use an array of 4 (or however many positions), to hold the "colour" (or number) of each location. Storing each value separately makes it much easier to work with than having them combined in a single integer value, which requires repeated divides and multiplies to manipulate the number. Likewise for the "right position, right number/wrong position" information would be stored in an array of 4 items.

You can use `std::array<int,4>` or `std::vector<> x(4);`, but many other alternatives are possible too - a class with a member array, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested for loops to iterate through each digit:

/* number = abcd*/

```
for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)//etc
```

and then you can possibly just address each one as `Math.pow(5,3) * a + Math.pow(5,2)*b+ ...` in an array of size 1295.

That should give you the array that you want.

Comment: Or one could use a single loop to iterate to the maximum integer value represented by 5555 in base 6..

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the obvious:

```
using namespace std;
using Number = uint16_t; // uint16_t holds up to 2^16 - 1 = 65535
Number const base = 6;

Number const max_number = 1295; /* = (6^4 - 1) */
vector<Number> numbers; 
numbers.reserve(static_cast<size_t>(max_number));
for (Number i = 0; i < max_number; ++i) {
    numbers.emplace_back(i);
}
```

In order to check your specific conditions, I'd convert the base 10 numbers to a "base 6 string", ie. a string that contains a base 6 representation for your numbers. Storing those is inefficient, but convenient to use temporarily. An example:

```
char char_rep(int n) { return static_cast<char>(n + 48); }

string representation(Number num) {
    string result("0000");
    for (size_t p = 0; p < 4; ++p) {
        result[3 - p] = char_rep(num % base);
        num /= base;
    }
    return move(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this is to create a class. The class needs to hold only a single `int` since there are less than 32767 possible values.

You need to decide how to store the value. I'd just use octal internally, and not bother with digits 6 and 7. Remember, you're not using all possible `int` values anyway, so there's no particular need to use just the first 1296 values.

Also, add getters and setters for each individual digit. This will make life easier, especially in your classes custom `operator<<(std::ostream&)`.